# Why can't I define an iterator on a string?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Here's a contrived example.

I can do this with an instance an array:

```js
function* cut () {
  for (let slice = 0; slice < 3; slice++) yield '';
}

const cake = [''];
cake[Symbol.iterator] = cut;
const slices = [...cake];
//=> ['', '', '']
```

But I cannot do the same with a string:

```js
const cake = '';
cake[Symbol.iterator] = cut;
const slices = [...cake];
//=> ['']
```

Why?

Comment: Primitives are immutable; enable strict mode to see the error.

Comment: @Ry- Ah yeah that makes sense! Seems obvious now ☺️

Comment: `const cake = newString('cake')`